# Python nested if-else only executed else

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, nested

I have this exercise , calculates the cost of sending a small parcel. Te post office charges R5 for the first 300g, and R2 for every 100g thereafter (rounded up), up to a maximum weight of 1000g .

```
weight = raw_input("What are the weight of you parcel: ")    

if weight <= 1000:
   if weight <= 300:
      cost = 5
     print("You parcel cost: " + cost)
   else:
      cost = 5 + 2 * round((weight - 300)/ 100)
      print("You parcel cost: " + cost)
else:
    print("Maximum weight for amall parcel exceeded.")
    print("Use large parcel service instead.")
```

When i execute the IDLE console , I come only the last else statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've got indentation problems. Two, you are comparing strings to ints. Then, compare...

```
>>> (350 - 300) / 100
0
>>> (350 - 300) / float(100)
0.5
```

You should check this yourself, but `round(0) = 0`, and `round(0.5) = 1`.

---

Here's the code that should fix the problems

```
weight = int(raw_input("What are the weight of you parcel: "))

if weight <= 1000:
  if weight <= 300:
    cost = 5
  else:
    cost = 5 + 2 * round((weight - 300) / float(100))
  print("Your parcel cost: {}".format(cost))
else:
  print("Maximum weight for small parcel exceeded.")
  print("Use large parcel service instead.")
```

Comment: Very Thanks , you code answer my question , but i think that you forget :

Comment: sorry... you forget : print("You parcel cost: " + str(cost))   , in if statement ..., now all it is veryyyyyyyy gut , thanks

Comment: No I didn't forget. You don't need two print statements - just print after and outside the else

Comment: You have to be more specific and finish your comments. I can't test all numbers, but `350` displays 7 and `300` displays 5. https://repl.it/EjQN/0

Comment: sorry ... , now a have copy and paste you code and all is GUT, sorry i have only my code corrective....

Answer (score 4):

Cast `weight` to an int, `weight = int(weight)`. Right now it's a string, which always evaluates to `False` when compared to 1000.

Comment: Thanks , i have what you tell me , but when i write 350 , not come the First else statements ...

Comment: If your code is as written, you have a spurious indent on the first `print` statement.

Comment: My answer addresses the 350 problem @iratxe It correctly goes into the inner else statement. Your math calculation is incorrect, causing cost to only be 5

Answer (score 1):

`weight` becomes a `string type` on line 1, then in the `if statement` you compare `weight` to an `int`. Fix this by converting the user input to int

Change your first line to:

```
weight = int(raw_input("What are the weight of you parcel: "))
```

Also if you are using python3 I would change `raw_input` to `input`

Comment: Isn't a string and int comparison supposed to raise a TypeError?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti thought the same but apparently in python3 only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I making this , and now i come : cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Comment: On this line `print("You parcel cost: " + cost)` you try to bring a string and float together, you need to convert the cost to a string like this: `print("You parcel cost: " + str(cost))`

Comment: Whit int is gut only with 300, when I write 350 i come : cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Answer (score 0):

float(Use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` for integers and don't try to concatenate strings and integers.

The following code works:

```
weight = input("What are the weight of you parcel: enter code here")

if weight <= 1000:
    if weight <= 300:
        cost = 5
        print("You parcel cost: " + str(cost))
    else:
        cost = 5 + 2 * round((weight - 300)/ float(100))
        print("You parcel cost: " + str(cost))

else:
    print("Maximum weight for amall parcel exceeded.")
    print("Use large parcel service instead.")
```

Comment: Even on Python 2.7? I am not familiar with 2.7 but I thought input would try to execute a Python code

Comment: Yes, when i write 350 , i come : cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Comment: The question was tagged as python27

Comment: Why when i write 350 , not come  the First else statements ??

Comment: Yes, in 2.7 using `input` evaluates it.

Answer (score 0):

Cast variable weight to a float when doing mathematics operation by

```
weight=float(input())
```

It will solve all the problems.